# map and mutate over a list of tbl_df

Tags: r

I am trying to map over a list of data frames in R but not getting it right. What I am trying is:

```
lst %>%
  map(~mutate(., NewColumn1 = .x$value*2,))
```

With error:

> Error: Column `NewColumn1` must be length 2 (the number of rows) or
>   one, not 0 In addition: Warning message: Unknown or uninitialised
>   column: 'value'.

The data looks like:

```
[[9]]
# A tibble: 2 x 4
  time       ID    Value   out
  <date>     <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 2016-12-23 CAT1   790.     0
2 2016-12-27 CAT1   792.     1

[[10]]
# A tibble: 2 x 4
  time       ID    Value   out
  <date>     <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 2016-12-28 CAT1   785.     0
2 2016-12-29 CAT1   783.     0
```

DATA:

```
Data <- list(structure(list(time = structure(c(17136, 17137), class = "Date"), 
    ID = c("CAT1", "CAT1"), Value = c(747.919983, 750.5), out = c(0, 
    1)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
)), structure(list(time = structure(c(17140, 17141), class = "Date"), 
    ID = c("CAT1", "CAT1"), Value = c(762.52002, 759.109985), 
    out = c(1, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")), structure(list(time = structure(c(17142, 
17143), class = "Date"), ID = c("CAT1", "CAT1"), Value = c(771.190002, 
776.419983), out = c(1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")), structure(list(time = structure(c(17144, 
17147), class = "Date"), ID = c("CAT1", "CAT1"), Value = c(789.289978, 
789.27002), out = c(1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")), structure(list(time = structure(c(17148, 
17149), class = "Date"), ID = c("CAT1", "CAT1"), Value = c(796.099976, 
797.070007), out = c(1, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")), structure(list(time = structure(c(17150, 
17151), class = "Date"), ID = c("CAT1", "CAT1"), Value = c(797.849976, 
790.799988), out = c(1, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")), structure(list(time = structure(c(17154, 
17155), class = "Date"), ID = c("CAT1", "CAT1"), Value = c(794.200012, 
796.419983), out = c(1, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")), structure(list(time = structure(c(17156, 
17157), class = "Date"), ID = c("CAT1", "CAT1"), Value = c(794.559998, 
791.26001), out = c(0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")), structure(list(time = structure(c(17158, 
17162), class = "Date"), ID = c("CAT1", "CAT1"), Value = c(789.909973, 
791.549988), out = c(0, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")), structure(list(time = structure(c(17163, 
17164), class = "Date"), ID = c("CAT1", "CAT1"), Value = c(785.049988, 
782.789978), out = c(0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the error message `Unknown or uninitialised column: 'value'.`, then look at your code `map(Data, ~mutate(., NewColumn1 = .x$value*2,))`. The column name is `Value` and not `value` (case is important!).

Your syntax can also be cleaned up a bit. Try `map(Data, ~mutate(., NewColumn1 = Value*2))`. Technically, I think `.` and `.x` refer to the same thing, but it's better to be consistent. In `mutate` you also don't need to subset the data frame, i.e. `mutate(df, new_col = old_col)` is enough, you don't need `mutate(df, new_col = .$old_col)`.